# sudo apt-get install php-redis stopped to work

Tags: php, redis, apt-get, circleci, phpredis

in our CircleCI build, we have a few months this installation of PHP redis but it stopped to work today. The return message is below.

Please, do you know how to fix it? I am a little confused what to do. Thank you for your help.

> sudo apt-get install php-redis Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> php-redis: Depends: php-igbinary but it is not going to be installed
>                Dep
>
> ends: phpapi-20160303 but it is not installable or
>                         phpapi-20151012 but it is not installable or
>                         phpapi-20131226 but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
>
> sudo apt-get install php-redis returned exit code 100
>
> Action failed: sudo apt-get install php-redis

Our flow in CircleCi looks like this:

- sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install php-redis
- echo 'extension=/usr/lib/php/20131226/redis.so' | sudo tee /opt/circleci/php/$(phpenv global)/etc/conf.d/redis.ini
- echo 'extension=/usr/lib/php/20131226/igbinary.so' | sudo tee /opt/circleci/php/$(phpenv global)/etc/conf.d/igbinary.ini

**SOLVED:**
use sudo apt-get -f install php-redis

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` it may fix dependencies or at least suggest you run `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: it seems that sudo apt-get -f install works! really thank you!

Comment: You might want to SSH in and figure out *why* you have to force it. Other stuff could be changing as a result of that. Newer versions of Ubuntu use `php7.0-redis`, so you may be force-installing PHP5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though there are other dependencies which are not installed by the main package. This usually happens to me when I install by `dpkg` (a downloaded Chrome deb package is the usual one).

When you run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It will usually tell you there has been some installation failure and suggests that you run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

These will usually resolve the dependencies and install any extra packages required.